# ¿Cómo pasar un Enum a array en un generic?

Tags: java

Quiero obtener el array de objetos de un `Enum` cuando desconozco este `Enum` ya que es el parámetro de un Generic. O sea, replicar lo que hace el método `values()` pero cuando desconozco cual es el `Enum`.

Éste es mi `Enum`:

```
enum ModosDeJuego{
    BASICO,
    ENTRENAMIENTO,
    DEMO
}
```

Ésta es mi clase genérica:

```
public class Menu<T extends Enum<T>>{
    private final T[] OPCIONES;
    Menu(T[] opciones){
        this.OPCIONES = opciones;
    }

  
    void imprimir(){
        for (int i = 0; i<OPCIONES.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(i + " " +  OPCIONES[i]);
        }        
    }


    T elegir(){
        /*Lógica que también implica la utilización del array OPCIONES...*/
    }

}
```

Ahora mismo ésta es la forma de implementar la clase:

```
Menu<ModosDeJuego> menu = new Menu<ModosDeJuego>(ModosDeJuego.values());
```

La parte que me quiero "ahorrar" es la del parámetro ya que se puede sacar a partir de la clase T.

Ésto es lo que he intentado hasta ahora:

```
this.OPCIONES = T.values();
```

Vi que recomiendan el uso de `EnumSet` y algunas otras cosas. Pero, no consigo implementarlas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al constructor de la clase `Menu` debes pasarle al menos la clase del `Enum`. Una posible solución sin llamar a `values()` sería cambiar tu constructor para recibir la clase del `Enum` y tomar los valores de las constantes con el método `getEnumConstants`. El constructor quedaría:

```java
Menu(Class<T> enumClass) {
    this.OPCIONES = enumClass.getEnumConstants();
}
```

Y para instanciar la clase usa:

```java
Menu<ModosDeJuego> menu = new Menu<>(ModosDeJuego.class);
```

Te dejo un link para que lo pruebes desde tu navegador https://onlinegdb.com/h3WYMbjNW